# R Read (Excel, txt...) rows and columns with conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

Supose I have this dataframe in a .dta, .txt or excel file:

```
ID fondo
1  colf
2  colf
3  prot
4  colf
5  porv
6  prot
7  porv
8  colf
9  colf
10  colf
```

I would like to read this file just the column 1 (`ID`) and the rows where `fondo == "colf"`. Then the final dataframe I would have in my R enviroment would be something like this:

```
ID
1
2
4
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several approaches.  The first two use only base R. The first one reads the entire file and then subsets it but does not save the original file, only column 1 of the subset.  The remaining ones exclude the non-`colf` rows and `fondo` column before or as they get to R.

**1)** Read in the file defined in the Note, subset it as indicated and then take the first column.

```
subset(read.table("myfile.dat", header = TRUE), fondo == "colf")[1]
```

giving:

```
   ID
1   1
2   2
4   4
8   8
9   9
10 10
```

**2)** Another possibility is to filter it before R.  This works in Windows.  Use grep instead of findstr if you are on Linux.

```
read.table(pipe("findstr colf myfile.dat"), colClasses = c(NA, "NULL"),
  col.names = c("ID", NA))
```

**3)** This alternative uses sqldf to read the file into an sqlite data base which it creates on the file and after extracting the desired rows only then reads it into R.  You may need to add the `eol=` argument depending on how the file was created and which operating system you are using.  See `?sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
read.csv.sql("myfile.dat", "select ID from file where fondo = 'colf'", sep = " ")
```

**4)** This is like (2) but uses `fread` from data.table. It uses findstr on Windows.  Replace that with grep if you are on Linux.

```
library(data.table)
fread("findstr colf myfile.dat", colClasses = c(NA, "NULL"), col.names = "ID")
```

**5)** This uses the fast command line utility [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) which needs to be installed.  It is available on all platforms that R is available and is unrelated to R -- it is written in Rust.  This does the reduction entirely in two invocations of xsv and then just reads what remains into R.  The following works on Windows but in some shells you may need to exchange the double and single quotes.

```
read.table(pipe('xsv search colf myfile.dat | xsv select -d " " ID'), header = TRUE)
```

### Note

```
d <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, fondo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("colf", "porv", "prot"), 
class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
write.table(d, "myfile.dat", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we read with `read.table/read.csv`

```
df1 <- read.csv('yourfile.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and then `subset` the dataset by `select`ing the 'ID' column while `subset`ing based on the condition

```
df2 <- subset(df1, select = 'ID', subset = fondo == 'colf')
```

---

If we need to do this while reading, use `read.sql` from `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
df1 <- read.csv.sql('yourfile.csv', sql = "select ID from file where fondo = 'colf'")
```